# do not concatenate text displayed with settext

Tags: android, location

How can i have bot the lat and log in one textview separated with a comma?
I tried as below and i am getting the "do not concatenate text displayed with settext" warning!

```
 gpsTracker = new GpsTracker( MainActivity.this);
               if(gpsTracker.canGetLocation()){
                   double latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
                   double longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();

                   textviewGPSLocation.setText(String.valueOf(latitude) + "/," + String.valueOf ( longitude ));
```

Comment: usually the IDE will recommend an alternative to these warnings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113625/do-not-concatenate-text-displayed-with-settext-use-resource-string-with-placeho)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Not really but thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format your string like this

```java
double latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
double longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
String text = String.format("%1$2f / %2$2f", latitude, longitude);
textviewGPSLocation.setText(text);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bruno. This worked as follows String text = `String.format(latitude+" , " longitude);
textviewGPSLocation.setText(text);`

Comment: If you're going to do this, you may as well just suppress the warning.  This just confuses the linter enough to not realize you've effectively written the same code a different way.  The idea is that some locales might express a latitude, longitude pair differently, and so you could use a string resource and translate it.  But...honestly, I don't think this is the sort of case where there's any real likelihood of confusion, so either this or suppressing the warning are fine.  It's effectively a false positive on the lint warning.